# How to use Smart Lock using Chrome browser?

Tags: smart-lock

Based on the following text, it seems Chrome browser can log in to a compatible mobile app with Smart Lock. Could someone help me learn how to do it by giving an example (maybe...)? Does that mean Chrome browser can unlock my smartphone as well? Sorry, I am not tech savvy. Thank you in advance !

"For Chrome and apps -
Skip the password guessing game. Smart Lock remembers your passwords within your Chrome browser and select mobile apps."

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is it possible to log in to the following app using Chrome browser? If so, how to go about? Thank thank you once again! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.konylabs.capitalone

Comment: Can't say.... App not available in my country for download :(

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply! Could I ask you then if Chrome browser is able to turn on and off a smartphone with Smart Lock? Thank you.